# How to share plan to users in stripe?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I just went through a research in stripe about their plans. And I found out that you can create, retrieve, update, and delete a plan given in the link's instruction. [stripe api](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/create)

I just want to ask, if there are some configs or instructions that allows doctors (subscriber's users) to access the plan? (see the image below)

For example, I have "Silver package" plan that can manage 100 doctors with a specified amount. Question is, does the stripe has a config or documentation that gives those 100 doctors access with the silver package? or we just work this in our own database.

[image]

Comment: @Ιησούςτουν yes the *Hospitals* are my customers, and *doctors* are the end users. their hospitals are with should be a suscriber in order to access app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Stripe Subscriptions do not have the capability to provision your product themselves. Subscriptions automate and track your customer’s recurring payment. A Subscription's `status` can be used to determine if it is safe to provision your product to your customer[1]; it is up to you to implement the provisioning logic yourself.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#subscription-statuses